# how to remove empty tuples to make it filter to print out all true result?

Tags: haskell

i do not know where the empty tuples coming from ?
since index is so big, i can not see the content of result

how to remove empty tuples to make it filter to print out all true result?

error:

*Main> let bb = filter (\n -> snd n == True) alltrees1

:74:39:
    Couldn't match expected type `(a0, Bool)' with actual type`()'
    Expected type: [(a0, Bool)]
      Actual type: [()]
    In the second argument of `filter', namely`alltrees1'
    In the expression: filter (\ n -> snd n == True) alltrees1

run:

```
:l trees.hs
let allparams = replicateM 3 [1.0, 2.0]
let alltrees = [getAllTrees c | x <- allparams, c <- [x]]
eval(alltrees!!1!!1) == eval(alltrees!!1!!1)
let alltrees1 = forM_ [0..(sizeoflist alltrees)] $ \i -> forM_ [0..(sizeoflist (alltrees!!i))] $ \j -> [(alltrees!!i!!j, eval(alltrees!!i!!j) == eval(alltrees!!i!!j))]
let bb = filter (\n -> if n != () then snd n == True) alltrees1
```

haskell:

```
import Data.List
import Control.Monad
import Math.Combinat
import System.IO

data Operation
  = And
  | Or
  | MA
  | MB
  | Impl
    deriving Show

data Mree x
 = Meaf x
 | Mode (Mree x) Operation (Mree x)
   deriving Show

splits :: [a] -> [([a], [a])]
splits xs = zip (inits xs) (tails xs)

getAllTrees :: [a] -> [Mree a]
getAllTrees [] = []
getAllTrees [x] = return $ Meaf x
getAllTrees xs = do
  (left, right) <- splits xs
  guard $ not (null left) && not (null right)
  leftT <- getAllTrees left
  rightT <- getAllTrees right
  op <- [And, Or]
  return $ Mode leftT op rightT

eval :: Mree Double -> Double
eval (Meaf x) = x
eval (Mode l And r) = eval l
eval (Mode l Or r) = eval r

sizeoflist :: [a] -> Int
sizeoflist = length
```

Comment: do not know where empty tuple coming from and how to filter them and print true result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the type of `altrees1` is `[()]`. By using `forM_` you are discarding the results of inner computations.

Note that the type of `altrees` is `[ [ Mree Double ] ]`.

Perhaps this is what you want:

```
allexprs :: [ Mree Double ]
allexprs = concat alltrees   -- a list of all the Mrees in alters

alltrees2 = [ (x, eval x == eval x) | x <- allexprs ]
   -- this is apparently what alltrees1 is doing

bb = [ x | (x, True) <- alltrees2 ]
   -- same as: filter (\(x,b) -> b == True) altrees2
   --          filter (\(x,b) -> b) alltrees2
   --          filter (\xb -> snd xb) alltrees2
```

Answer (score 0):

The basic haskell List (and most collections) won't let you store empty tuples and non-empty tuples in the same list, because they are different types—so, in this case, it doesn't make sense to say

```
\n -> if n != () then snd n == True
```

Now: why is the list a list of empty tuples? Because of the type of forM_ (found via [hoogle](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=forM_)):

```
forM_ :: (Foldable t, Monad m) => t a -> (a -> m b) -> m ()
```

In the context above (iterating over a list, producing a list), this is specifically:

```
forM_ :: [a] -> (a -> [b]) -> [()]
```

The return value from forM_ (and, as a naming convention, many functions ending with underscore, like traverse_, for_, and sequenceA_) is "useless"; these functions are typically used to execute side effects in some monad like IO.

Note: since you aren't using those indices for anything but to visit each list member, it'd be a little cleaner to just use map:

```
map (map (\x -> (x, eval x == eval x))) allTrees
```

For more info about lists, see [the chapter from the book learn you a haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/starting-out#an-intro-to-lists).